# TypeScript & React: reusable generic actions / components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-reducer, redux-reducers

I use TypeScript with React and useReducer and I want to define reducer Actions in a type-safe way.

The simplest approximation of Action is:

```
type Action = {name : string, payload : any}
```

The more precise version requires union types:

```
type Action =
  | {name : "setColumns", payload: string[]}
  | {name : "toggleColumn", payload: string}
  ...
```

So far so good. Then I want to define components which depend on Action or rather on its derivative `React.Dispatch<Action>`. There are two ways to do that:

1. Accept (multiple) generics
2. Define wider types

The approach 1) is more type-safe in theory yet much more verbose and complex in practice.
The approach 2) can be a good balance between safety and complexity.

Example of `Pager` component props in both styles:

```
// 1)
export type PagerProps1 <Page extends number, Limit extends number> = {
  page : Page // -- narrower types
  limit : Limit
  pagesTotal : number
}

// 2)
export type PagerProps2 = {
  page : number // -- wider types
  limit : number
  pagesTotal : number
}
```

^ now it's possible to define `Pager2` and move it to the library with no dependency on `Page` and `Limit` which are app-specific. And without generics. That was the intro to provide necessary context.

The problem comes with `React.Dispatch`. Here's the test-case that imitates reusal of generic dispatch in place where more precise version is present:

```
type Action =
  | {name : "setColumn"}
  | {name : "toggleColumn"}

type OpaqueAction1 = {name : any}    // will work
type OpaqueAction2 = {name : string} // will not work

type Dispatch = React.Dispatch<Action>
type OpaqueDispatch1 = React.Dispatch<OpaqueAction1> // will work
type OpaqueDispatch2 = React.Dispatch<OpaqueAction2> // will not work

export const DemoComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = React.useReducer(() => null, null)[1]
  const d0 : Dispatch = dispatch
  const d1 : OpaqueDispatch1 = d0 // ok
  const d2 : OpaqueDispatch2 = d0 // type error
}
```

The error is the following:

```
TS2322: Type 'Dispatch<Action>' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<OpaqueAction2>'.   
Type 'OpaqueAction2' is not assignable to type 'Action'.     
Type 'OpaqueAction2' is not assignable to type '{ name: "toggleColumn"; }'.       
Types of property 'name' are incompatible.         
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"toggleColumn"'.
```

^ **but in the code above we actually assign `"toggleColumn"` to `string`. Something is wrong.**

Here is the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-butterfly-yldoq?file=/src/App.tsx:504-544

Comment: When you are dealing with a function like dispatch, one which accepts a wider set of argument types extends one which accepts a narrower set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not assigning `"toggleColumn"` to `string`, you're assigning `Dispatch<Action>` to `Dispatch<OpaqueAction2>`.

The problem is that `Dispatch<Action>` is a function that can only handle a parameter with a `name` property `"toggleColumn"`, while `Dispatch<OpaqueAction2>` is a function that can handle a parameter with a `name` property of any `string` type. The assignment implies that `Dispatch<Action>` should be able to handle any `string` type as well, but it can't.

A function `(...args: T) => R` is assignable to `(...args: U) => R` if and only if `U` is assignable to `T`. This is why the first two lines of your error message reverse the order of the types:

```
Type 'Dispatch<Action>' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<OpaqueAction2>'.   
Type 'OpaqueAction2' is not assignable to type 'Action'.
```

Comment: Yes, good catch. Anyone interested in details should search for "functions contravarience".